# Is it possible to save a react Js rendered page to html and / or pdf server side?

Tags: reactjs, django, pdf

This is more of a general question, hence I'm not including any code.

I've looked at quite a few options for both pdf and html, but haven't figured out a good solution.

I'm trying to take the output of what would be rendered by reactJs in a browser and save it to the hosting server instead of (or as well as) displaying it in the browser.

Specifically I'm generating a report using a pretty standard React functions, styled with css, and want to save that report upon rendering to the server.

The API which I also control is Django based.

I've looked at react-pdf/renderer, react-pdf, pdfkit on the Django side (w/wkhtmltopdf), reactdomserver to generate static html files, but can't quite piece together a solution.

Would love some feedback if anyone's done something like this before.